# What classifies a question as a "hot network question"?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I've seen a few "Hot Network Questions" recently that seem... not so hot.

For example, [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/27901/first-paper-to-introduce-the-principal-agent-problem) has one answer, one question, and four votes altogether.

Is this accurate? Perhaps someone could check this question and prove me wrong?

If it is, what exactly classifies it as a "hot network question"?

Comment: (actually all questions should have one question.)

Comment: I'd refer to it as *relatively* hot—ceteris paribus. After all, the site's in beta. :-)

Comment: Funnily enough, this question is now in itself a "hot meta post".

Comment: I don't mean to brag but I once had three of my questions from several SE accounts in the HNQ section at once, [proof](https://imgur.com/gallery/Plh3cMw).

Comment: “Warm”, then, @Trebled?

Comment: This section is a Game of Thrones spoiler at the moment

Comment: Relatively *Hot*

Comment: @Cody Nawww, I wasn't looking for a word change. It's more like touching those extreme-temperature exhibits in a science museum, you know, some claim to feel 1k Kelvin while some claim 6 to 8...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It meets a lot of the [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/284336) for hot questions and it's a slow day, being Sunday and Easter.

The question is upvoted, it was answered quickly and that answer has several votes (3 as of writing).

In the formula, new questions (<6 hours) with an answer and some votes are considered really hot. This particular question probably isn't *really* hot but, as I said at the top, there's not a lot of competition right now.